# React component find last-of-type class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

I have a Accordion which contain selected medication.
There are 3 types (Current, Prescribed and Recommended)

I want to have a 15px bottom margin between types.

I have them identified in classes `panel-head-color1` , `panel-head-color2` and `panel-head-color3`, this was done to color-code the different types.

But on the spacing, I want the last element of each class to have a `margin-bottom:15px`

Ive tried something like in `CSS`,

```
div.panel-head-color1:last-of-type,
div.panel-head-color2:last-of-type,
div.panel-head-color3:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

But that does not work. Im thinking about JQuery, but im unsure how you would do something like it in a React component.

This is what im after.

[image]

CURRENT CSS

```
.panel-head-color1 > .panel-heading{
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-head-color2 > .panel-heading{
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  color: #222222;
}

.panel-head-color3 > .panel-heading{
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  color: #222222;
}

.panel-head-color1,
.panel-head-color2,
.panel-head-color3{
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}


.last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.panel-head-color1').last().addClass('last-of-type');
    $('.panel-head-color2').last().addClass('last-of-type');
    $('.panel-head-color3').last().addClass('last-of-type');
},
```

**css**

```
.last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count which element is last-of-type in react and put there the appropriate class `.last-of-type`

But if you dont want to complicate your react javascript code the external javascript or jQuery code also is not a bad idea. I would recommend vanila JS because of the speed, but if you are already using jQuery so it doesn't matter.

Vanila JS:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-head-color2');
elements[elements.length-1].classList.add('last-of-type');
```

jQuery:

```
$('.panel-head-color2').last().addClass('last-of-type');
```

Comment: Thank, can you please explain how or where to apply this JS.
Inside the render just like that?  I tried it in there but i get a `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined`

Comment: inside `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-bottom` instead of `margin-bottom` and see the result.

Comment: The point is that I need to apply this `style` to only the last occurrence of each class type. The margin-bottom works great ( I did in manually above in the screenshot), but getting code to identify where to apply this style is what im after. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you mean you won't know how many elements are there in each type?

Comment: nope. medications are selected and given a type. This type has a specific class which you can see with the colors for each type. But to brin a seperation between types, I need to select only the last class of each type and apply the margin.

Comment: did you try `div :last-child` ?

Comment: not yet, elaborate please. Not sure if it will work. because all the entries are siblings.

Comment: can you provide existing css you have please?